# jsMath and font styling

Tags: javascript

This is my first time on this board so I apologize if I seem a little lost. I am also fairly new using JavaScript as well, so just keep that in mind. I am using Sublime Text if it helps.

I want to write some kind of program that solves differential equations. Thus far I am merely getting a feel for what I have to do, and how I am going to do it. My code so far is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(slct1) {
        var s1 = document.getElementById(slct1);
        if (s1.value == "Linear First Order Differential Equation") {
            var m1 = "A linear first order differential equation is one of the form: \n" + "                                y' + f(x)y = r(x) \n" + "Is this correct?";
                if (confirm(m1))
                    var m11 = "In order to solve such a differential equation, we must plug in the respective values for f(x) and r(x). Click OK to advance to the  next step.";
                        if (confirm(m11))
                            console.log("TestTest");
                else 
                    console.log("Test");
        } else if (s1.value == "Cat2") {
            var m2 = "Yes";
                if (confirm(m2))
                 console.log("It works");
                else 
                 console.log("Still working");


        } else if (s1.value == "Cat3") {
            var something = "some stuff, etc.";
    }


}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Differential Equations Solver v1.0</h2>
<hr />
Choose the form of the differential equation:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id, 'slct2')">
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="Linear First Order Differential Equation">Linear First Order Differential Equation</option>
   <option value="Cat2">Cat2</option>
   <option value="Cat3">Cat3</option>
</select>
<hr />

</body>
</html>
```

A few things I wanted to clear up:

How do I implement jsMath? Especially using console.log? I don't want any equations being limited to the dreariness of Sans Serif.

After choosing a Linear First Order Diff Eq and clicking OK, the next message (var m11) is displayed in a different font than the first window. Why is this and how do I correct it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the font of the alert box. You can however change the font of the HTML using CSS. In the plunkr below, i have changed the font in a seperate css file and included that file into the head.

From a cursory google search, it seems like jsMath has been replaced by MathJax. One way of enabling it will be to include it as a script in your head.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async
src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML"></script>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/aU5eUdJgEpVOncNB7Gnl?p=preview

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.